# libxml fails to parse correctly

Tags: php, libxml2

For some reason , libxml fails to get the text correctly from a page. What I want to get the text "In last few days ..." which is the main text of the article, but libxml exits saying that it couldn't find the end tag of some start tag. This is the code:

```
[niko@dev1 tmp]$ cat domtest2.php 
<?php

    $url="http://www.journaldev.com/253/65-html5-tutorials-examples-and-resources-for-web-developers";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $htmltext=curl_exec($ch);

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $result=$dom->loadHTML($htmltext);
    $full_text=$dom->textContent;

    echo $full_text;
?>
[niko@dev1 tmp]$
```

Code output:

```
[niko@dev1 tmp]$ php -f domtest2.php
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <head> tag in Entity, line: 57 in /tmp/domtest2.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/domtest2.php:0
PHP   2. DOMDocument->loadHTML() /tmp/domtest2.php:10
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 69 in /tmp/domtest2.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/domtest2.php:0
PHP   2. DOMDocument->loadHTML() /tmp/domtest2.php:10
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): AttValue: " expected in Entity, line: 76 in /tmp/domtest2.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/domtest2.php:0
PHP   2. DOMDocument->loadHTML() /tmp/domtest2.php:10
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 76 in /tmp/domtest2.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/domtest2.php:0
PHP   2. DOMDocument->loadHTML() /tmp/domtest2.php:10
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Couldn't find end of Start Tag section in Entity, line: 76 in /tmp/domtest2.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/domtest2.php:0
PHP   2. DOMDocument->loadHTML() /tmp/domtest2.php:10
65 HTML5 Tutorials, Examples and Resources for Web Developers - JournalDevwindow._wpemojiSettings={"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/www.journaldev.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js"}};!function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c,d,e,f=b.createElement("canvas"),g=f.getContext&&f.getContext("2d"),h=String.fromCharCode;if(!g||!g.fillText)return!1;switch(g.textBaseline="top",g.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return g.fillText(h(55356,56806,55356,56826),0,0),f.toDataURL().length>3e3;case"diversity":return g.fillText(h(55356,57221),0,0),c=g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,d=c[0]+","+c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],g.fillText(h(55356,57221,55356,57343),0,0),c=g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,e=c[0]+","+c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],d!==e;case"simple":return g.fillText(h(55357,56835),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode8":return g.fillText(h(55356,57135),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0]}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i;for(i=Array("simple","flag","unicode8","diversity"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);img.wp-smiley,img.emoji{display:inline !important;border:none !important;box-shadow:none !important;height:1em !important;width:1em !important;margin:0
.07em !important;vertical-align:-0.1em !important;background:none !important;padding:0
!important}jQuery(function(){jQuery('.wpdm-popup').click(function(){tb_show(jQuery(this).html(),this.href+'&modal=1&width=600&height=400');return false;});jQuery('.haspass').click(function(){var url=jQuery(this).attr('href');var id=jQuery(this).attr('rel');var password=jQuery('#pass_'+id).val();jQuery.post('http://www.journaldev.com/',{download:id,password:password},function(res){if(res=='error'){jQuery('#wpdm_file_'+id+' .perror').html('Wrong Password');setTimeout("jQuery('#wpdm_file_"+id+" .perror').html('');",3000);return false;}else{location.href='http://www.journaldev.com/?wpdmact=process&did='+res;}});return false;});}).enews
.screenread{height:1px;left:-1000em;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-1000em;width:1px}(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create','UA-12171637-4','auto');ga('send','pageview');.site-title
a{background:url(http://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cropped-Final-JD-Logo.png) no-repeat !important}.simple-social-icons ul li a, .simple-social-icons ul li a:hover{background-color:#f6f5f2 !important;border-radius:3px;color:#aaa !important;border:0px
#fff solid !important;font-size:18px;padding:9px}.simple-social-icons ul li a:hover{background-color:#000 !important;border-color:#fff !important;color:#fff !important}.mctb-bar,.mctb-response,.mctb-close{background:#f7682c !important}.mctb-bar,.mctb-label,.mctb-close{color:#fff !important}.mctb-button{background:#096abf !important;border-color:#096abf !important}.mctb-email:focus{outline-color:#096abf !important}.mctb-button{color:#fff !important}JournalDevJava, Java EE, Android, Web Development Tutorials
[niko@dev1 tmp]$
```

How can I find what is wrong here? You can reproduce this error if you copy the code and run in your terminal. Also, I want to point out that when I copied manually the html source from the url into a file and ran the test it worked, so I suspect there might be something with encoding. However, the article is written in english, doesn't make sense.

Comment: I get the same problems as you do. But copying the source manually or saving it as a file first did not work for me either. The HTML you are about to parse seem to be to broken to be read correctly. Finding content via XPath failed as well. If you really need to get the data I suggest you try the manual way, with using RexEx or simple string search.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag probably when I copied it, my editor fixed the bad tags. Thanks for testing my code. After spending 1 day on it, I concluded that it is a problem with libxml. I used Google's Gumbo parser and it worked on the source file I provided as example. So, I moved to Gumbo for doing parsing with the disadvantage of writing the parsing code in C and calling it from php with exec()